# Comma Separated values with oracle Query

Tags: sql, database, oracle

i have table

```
id product     sharedwith  createdby   proddesc
1 100           78          71          ABC
2 200           73,45,46    71          LMN
3 300           45,46       78          IJK
```

i wont to display all product which created by 78 and also shared with 78

Comment: Include your attempt please.

Answer (score 1):

```
where createdby = 78 or instr(','||sharedwith||',', ',78,') > 0
```